# Formula Error with 4 charts

Tags: excel

I have created vlookup to sum for 4 charts but it keeps saying "The formula you type contains an error. What do I missing? This is what I typed. It works fine with two charts like this:

```
=SUM(VLOOKUP("John Patrick",$B$39:$C$50,2,FALSE),(VLOOKUP("John Patrick",$E$39:$F$50,2,FALSE)))
```

but not with 4 charts below. I attached the images, and you will notice on 4 charts.

```
=SUM(VLOOKUP("John Patrick",$B$39:$C$50,2,FALSE),
    (VLOOKUP("John Patrick",$E$39:$F$50,2,FALSE),
    (VLOOKUP(“John Patrick”,$H$39:$I$50,2,FALSE),
    (VLOOKUP(“John Patrick”,$K$39:$L$50,2,FALSE),
    (VLOOKUP(“John Patrick”,$N$39:$O$50,2,FALSE)))
```

I tried to attach the image but it keeps "You need at least 10 reputation to post image" I do not what this talking about, script?

Update: Here's the screenshot.

[image]

Comment: I copy your edited and paste into excel formula is still error. Where do I need to attach image that will help you understand what I am talking about.

Answer (score 0):

```
=SUM(VLOOKUP("John Patrick",$B$39:$C$50,2,FALSE),
    (VLOOKUP("John Patrick",$E$39:$F$50,2,FALSE),
    (VLOOKUP(“John Patrick”,$H$39:$I$50,2,FALSE),
    (VLOOKUP(“John Patrick”,$K$39:$L$50,2,FALSE),
    (VLOOKUP(“John Patrick”,$N$39:$O$50,2,FALSE)))
```

I think you have an extra '(' before each VLOOKUP in lines 2, 3, 4, and 5.
And an extra ')' at the end.

(At least, I think you are trying to add all the values)

This is the corrected formula:

```
=SUM(VLOOKUP("John Patrick",$B$39:$C$50,2,FALSE),
     VLOOKUP("John Patrick",$E$39:$F$50,2,FALSE),
     VLOOKUP(“John Patrick”,$H$39:$I$50,2,FALSE),
     VLOOKUP(“John Patrick”,$K$39:$L$50,2,FALSE),
     VLOOKUP(“John Patrick”,$N$39:$O$50,2,FALSE))
```

Comment: It is still an error "The formula you type contains an error" so are you sure this is correct formula below.

Comment: =SUM(VLOOKUP("John Patrick",$B$39:$C$50,2,FALSE),
    (VLOOKUP("John Patrick",$E$39:$F$50,2,FALSE),
    (VLOOKUP(“John Patrick”,$H$39:$I$50,2,FALSE),
    (VLOOKUP(“John Patrick”,$K$39:$L$50,2,FALSE),
    (VLOOKUP(“John Patrick”,$N$39:$O$50,2,FALSE)))

Comment: Yes I am trying to sum total of all value from 4 charts under John Patrick.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe (five tables):

```
=SUMIF(B$39:N$50,B54,C$39:O$50)
```